# How to convert an array to json in yii2

Tags: rest, yii2

I am creating `restful apis` and I had a function to send response data in `yii1` like this

```
public function sendResponse($data)
{
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo CJSON::encode($data);
    exit;
}
```

`CJSON` is not available in `Yii2` so how do i do it in `Yii2`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No need to manually set header like that.

In the specific action / method you can set it like so:

```
use Yii;
use yii\web\Response;

...

public function actionIndex()
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
}
```

Then after that just return a simple array like that:

```
return ['param' => $value];
```

You can find this property in official docs [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html#$format-detail).

For more than one action using special `ContentNegotiator` filter is more flexible approach:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
            'only' => ['index', 'view']
            'formats' => [
                'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

There are more settings, you can check it in [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-contentnegotiator.html).

As for the REST, base [yii\rest\Controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-controller.html) already has it set for `json` and `xml`:

```
'contentNegotiator' => [
    'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
    'formats' => [
        'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
        'application/xml' => Response::FORMAT_XML,
    ],
],
```

Comment: Thanks arogachev for great information. although my question was just on how to json encode in yii2 , you added a great info on settings headers Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

::find()->asArray()->all();
wish help.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Json class in yii2 from

```
yii\helpers\Json;
```

It contain methods such as :

```
Json::encode();
Json::decode();
```

These methods directly converts yii2 activerecord objects into json array.